# only get validated data from laravel validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation

When validating data with the validator, it's possible to get all processed data from the validator using the `getData()` method. However, that returns all data that has been passed into the validator. I only want the data that actually fit the validation pattern.

For example:

```
$data = [
    'email'          => email@example.com,
    'unnecessaryKey' => 'whatever'
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'email'       => 'required|string',
]);

$validator->getData()
```

Would return the "unnecessaryKey" as well as the email. The question is: Is it possible to only return the email in this case, even though i passed in  unnecessaryKey as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are getting the data from the $request you can try

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->only('email') , [
        'email'       => 'required|string',
]);
```

if you are validating a  $data array then you can try

```
$validator = Validator::make(collect($data)->only('email')->toArray() , [
        'email'       => 'required|string',
]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests) for this.

1. Create a Form Request Class

`php artisan make:request StoreBlogPost`

2. Add Rules to the Class, created at the app/Http/Requests directory.

```
public function rules()
    {
      return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
      ];
    }
```

3. Retrieve the request in your controller, it's already validated.

```
public function store(StoreBlogPost $request)
{
   // The incoming request is valid...
   // Retrieve the validated input data...
   $validated = $request->validated();
}
```